# Having trouble connecting to the SQL Server Management Studio database

Tags: ssms

I've newly installed SQL Server Management Studio ("SSMS") and tried to connect to the database which is the first login screen that opens upon opening the application. I've watched videos online regarding how to connect to the database and I've understood the steps however, when I logged in with the appropriate windows credentials, it gave me the below mentioned error:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JJag.png)

I'm new to SSMS (probably the issue) and watching tutorials online where the instructor uses SSMS.

Operating System: Windows 10
SSMS Details -
Release number: 18.3
Build number: 15.0.18178.0
Release date: September 23, 2019

This is personal computer and not a company system. The server I'm trying to connect to is the local machine itself using my windows credentials to the Database engine.

**Copied error message:**

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to local.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

---

The network path was not found

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Comment: Have you installed SQL Server? If yes, Please follow this link: https://www.lansweeper.com/knowledgebase/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred/ . Please let me know how you go.

Comment: No I haven't. I've only installed SSMS. Is it necessary to install SQL Server as well to get going?. The video is helpful however it specifies changes that need me to get past that first log in screen. Anyway, will give it a check based on this method.

Comment: In the name `SQL Server Management Studio`,  Management Studio is important. It's just an "IDE". From the documentation '_SSMS is an integrated environment for managing any SQL infrastructure, from SQL Server to Azure SQL Database. SSMS provides tools to configure, monitor, and administer instances of SQL Server and databases. Use SSMS to deploy, monitor, and upgrade the data-tier components used by your applications, and build queries and scripts.
Use SSMS to query, design, and manage your databases and data warehouses, wherever they are - on your local computer, or in the cloud.!_'

Comment: You still need a Database of some sort, and something to Host it. You can compare SSMS to PhpMyAdmin, It still need a SQL base somewhere. It can be almost any Database/host

Comment: I'm inclined to think this has something to do with the internet connection or something that I've not done prior to entering the login credentials. Will give it a try as per the link posted by @MaheshWaghmare. Was unable to do so due to some maintenance. Will report back in case of a breakthrough, else will seek further guidance.

Comment: Any issue with this question for receiving a down-vote?. Please let me know so that I can refine it as per the site standards.

Comment: Here's one possible reason: [images of errors are not helpful.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception) If you look on that error dialog, there's even a link to copy the error message https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjeH8.png. You should do so and copy the text into an [edit]. In addition, you don't let us know anything about the server you're trying to connect to. Is it on your local machine? On the local area network? Or is it over the internet? There are LOTS of reasons why you might have this problem, including the server not configured properly.

Comment: @Will understood. I've edited the question a bit better. Let me know if I've missed anything. Will yet update the question with the 'Error Message' but I cannot do so now as there is some maintenance work going on on it. However, to answer your other question, I'm trying to connect to the local machine. I will create a database once I'm through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to find out the issue. This is if you are a new user trying to use SQL Server Management Studio for the first time on your local machine.

**To start SQL Server Management Studio**

On current versions of Windows, on the **Start** page, type SSMS, and then click **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**.

When using older versions of Windows, on the **Start** menu, point to **All Programs**, point to **Microsoft SQL Server 2017**, and then click SQL Server Management Studio.

**To determine the name of the instance of the Database Engine**

1. Log into Windows as a member of the Administrators group, and open Management Studio.
2. In the **Connect to Server** dialog box, click **Cancel**.
3. If Registered Servers is not displayed, on the **View** menu, click **Registered Servers**.
4. With **Database Engine** selected on the Registered Servers toolbar, expand **Database Engine**, right-click **Local Server Groups**, point to Tasks, and then click **Register Local Servers**. All instances of the Database Engine installed on the computer are displayed. The default instance is unnamed and is shown as the computer name. A named instance displays as the computer name followed by a backward slash `(\)` and then the name of the instance. For SQL Server Express, the instance is named `<computer_name>\sqlexpress` unless the name was changed during setup.

**To verify that the Database Engine is running**

In Registered Servers, if the name of your instance of SQL Server has a green dot with a white arrow next to the name, the Database Engine is running and no further action is necessary.

If the name of your instance of SQL Server has a red dot with a white square next to the name, the Database Engine is stopped. Right-click the name of the Database Engine, click **Service Control**, and then click **Start**. After a confirmation dialog box, the Database Engine should start and the circle should turn green with a white arrow.

**To connect to the Database Engine**

At least one administrator account was selected when SQL Server was being installed. Perform the following step while logged into Windows as an administrator.

1. In Management Studio, on the **File** menu, click **Connect Object Explorer**.

   - The Connect to Server dialog box opens. The **Server type** box displays the type of component that was last used.
2. Select **Database Engine**.
3. In the **Server name** box, type the name of the instance of the Database Engine. For the default instance of SQL Server, the server name is the computer name. For a named instance of SQL Server, the server name is the `<computer_name>\<instance_name>`, such as **ACCTG_SRVR\SQLEXPRESS**.

It should work.